# Create/generate style from properties automatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, markup

I have a XAML Markup with multiple lines.

```
<telerik:RadTileView x:Name="RadTileView"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         Height="480"
                                         Margin="40"
                                         ColumnWidth="160"
                                         RowHeight="160"
                                         ColumnsCount="4"
                                         RowsCount="3"
                                         MaxRows="3"
                                         IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                         MaximizeMode="Zero"
                                         SelectionMode="Single"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
                                         ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource TileItemDataTemplate}">
```

Now I am done developing I want to simplify my markup and put the properties into a style.

But then I have to create a new Style and copy and paste each and ever property into it.

Is there an extension or addon to do the work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend has (or at least did in Expression Blend) this functionality.

[Extract styles in Expression Blend](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2010/01/19/extract-styles-in-expression-blend.aspx)